# SQL: Distinct and Distinct count(*) With Hive Tables

Tags: sql, hive

I am getting two very different numbers for these seemingly similar queries on (hive) tables:

```
select count(*) from test
# result: 2609173
```

```
select distinct count(*) from test
# result: 2609173
```

```
insert into testToo
select distinct * from test
# result: inserted 673065 rows
```

Any recommendations on how I might be able to discern what is going on? Am I using distinct somehow differently in the first few queries?

Comment: select count(distinct *) from test

Comment: distincting the result of select count(\*) is the same as count(\*) - you are simply saying give me the distinct results of count(\*), but that is only one result and of course distincting that result is also one result - remember, you are distincting one value, the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `select count(distinct *) from test` rather than `select distinct count(*) from test`

The former means "select the count of distinct rows" and the latter means "select the distinct values of count(*)" (and there's only one value so it is semantically the same as `select count(*) from test`)